# MySQL Decimals ignoring Logical Operators

Tags: mysql, operators, decimal

`utility` is a `DECIMAL(10,2)` column.

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE utility >= 50
```

This query returns things that have a utility of 4.25, for example. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that utility is a decimal? Sounds like some character conversion is going on. Can you post the output of `show create table items`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE utility >= CAST(50 AS DECIMAL(10,2));

SELECT * FROM items WHERE utility >= 50.0;
```